# MySQL - count users WHERE (last 30 days, last one year, all time)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a query that checks the clients table and returns a count of users with a specific value for the **last 30 days, 365 days and All Time**.

The all time count is easy:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT count(id) AS count FROM clients WHERE referred =  :refid");
$stmt->bindParam(':refid', $refid);
$stmt->execute();
$totalreferrals = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Table:

```
id |   signup   | reffered |
----------------------------
2  | 2012-08-24 |   14     |
----------------------------
3  | 2011-10-13 |   14     |
```

I am not sure if I can combine the query using a UNION or if I should just make three different queries. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think you want this in columns and not in rows if so here it is

```
SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),signup) <= 30 THEN id
                   ELSE NULL
              END) AS Last30days ,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), signup) <= 365 THEN id
                   ELSE NULL
              END) AS Last365Days ,
        COUNT(*) AS Alltime
FROM    Table1
WHERE   reffered = 14
```

SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e6ce/2

Comment: I like this solution. Never used the WHEN statement before.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could solve the problem:

```
SELECT count(id) AS count FROM clients WHERE referred = :refid AND BETWEEN ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH) AND NOW();

SELECT count(id) AS count FROM clients WHERE referred = :refid AND BETWEEN ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 YEAR) AND NOW();
```